# Checking for cookies results in an error in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I trying to create a system that checks if you have visited the site before or if you are new via cookies that is written in PHP.

The code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {                 //Checking for cookie, this is line 2
    echo "You have visited before";
}else{                                          //If there is no cookie
    echo "Welcome to this site!";
    setcookie("cookie", "cookie_is_set", );     //Setting cookie because user has visited
};
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

*Notice: Undefined index: cookie in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cookietest\index.php on line 2*

After looking at other people's code, I suspect that the cause of this is some error in my PHP or something... so should I disable it or what, and how? Is there some other problem?

Thanks for answering in advance, San Bergam

Comment: If you explicitly set $_COOKIE['cookie'] to something then test if isset, do you get the error?

Comment: I think you might be looking at the wrong code, there's no `['fun']` index referred in your code.

Comment: put your correct code @San Bergam

Answer (score 0):

Seem have no error in your code. In your error message, "Notice: Undefined index: fun". But in your code, I don't see "fun" index.

We have 2 ways to check cookie exists

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
}
else{
    // Cookie is not set
}
```

or

```
if(array_key_exists('cookie', $_COOKIE)) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
} else {
    // Cookie is not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your code anyway that isn't related to the index 'fun'. It's also quite possible that if you're testing on Window, the results are being cached in the browser and also by the OS. I've come across this issue quite often when testing on Windows.

Your error:

setcookie("cookie", "cookie_is_set"**, );**

According to the manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

`bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )`

You can pass a name & string value and the cookie will expire at the end of the session, typically when the browser is closed, or your cache is manually cleared while the browse is open.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    echo "You have visited before";
} else {
    setcookie("cookie", "cookie_is_set", 0);
    echo "Welcome to this site!";
}
```

If you drop the code into a console using `php -a` in windows or *nix, the message `"Welcome to this site!"` will be printed. The same will also happen if you drop that into a php file, eg. index.php, but on subsequent refreshes, the message `"You have visited before"` will show.